# object equals and class equals conflict

Tags: hibernate, equals

We have a hibernate in place and we are facing an issue with one of the DAO class. When I get the List of objects from query following is problem we are facing.

1. We have implemented equals method where we call getClass which for some of the objects from the list returns ClassDO$$jsxx (having additional extension $$jsxx) due to this the comparison is failing.
2. When we remove this equals implementation then default object behavior returns true for the same object.

There is no inner class implemented.
Can someone kindly help why this getClass is returning this different object.
If we class this object into actual class it returns the object but getter call does not return anything.

Comment: Post your code please where in equals is overridden

Comment: Hibernate uses dynamic Javassist proxies to implement lazy associations, or when using session.load() or entityManager.getReference(). ClassDO$$jsxx is the class of such a javassist proxy. You should use instanceof instead of getClass() in your equals() method (if you really want an equals() method).

Comment: Hello JB, even instance of is pointing to the proxy class. Due to this we are not even able to utilise it. And strangely this is appearing only for some selected items . Not for all.